# How to mutate a variable passed by reference from C# to Rust?

Tags: c#, rust, reference, ffi

I would like to pass variable by reference to Rust, so it is not going to be copied every time I call the function. My code so far:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn random_number(mut _number: &i32){
    println!("Hello world from rust - random_number");
    _number = &50;
}
```

```cs
[DllImport("rust_to_cs.dll")]
static extern void random_number(ref int number);

var result = 36;
random_number(ref result);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The result I am getting

```
Hello world from rust - random_number
36
```

Calling the function is working but the variable is copied not passed by reference.

Comment: Related: [Some confusion about the mutability of a reference and the mutability of the value a reference refers to](/q/64002601/2189130)

Comment: Well technically the variable isn't copied, but you change the pointer instead of the pointee.

Comment: I did notice you've named your variable `_number` instead of `number` presumably because the [Rust compiler warned you that it was unused](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5622eddc5efa9e0e771a0fbc13b2e11c) and that was the way you took to suppress the warning. You should probably not do that unless you understand the warning and implications thereof.

Answer (score 1):

I need to change rust function to something like this

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn random_number(number: &mut i32){
    println!("Hello world from rust - random_number");
    *number = 50;
}
```

Instead of `random_number(mut _number: &i32)` I have `random_number(number: &mut i32)`

Assigning new value has been also changed from `_number = &50;` to `*number = 50;`

Now I got following result

```
Hello world from rust - random_number
50
```